# How to find count of items in googlesheet where cell can have leading and trailing spaces?

Tags: google-sheets

I was trying to find the count of cities having COUNT > 1 in google sheet but the problem is that some of the cities have leading or trailing spaces.

Shared google sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10NzbtJhQj4hQBnZXcmwise3bLBIAWrE0qwSus_bz7a0/edit#gid=8060956

My attempt

```sql
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(D1:D&{"",""},"select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 != '' group by Col1 order by count(Col2) desc",1))
```

Data:

```
SN  Company         Place                City
1   Cardinal Health Dublin, OH           Dublin
2   McDonald        Chicago, IL           Chicago
3   Nielson         Chicago, IL, NY, FL  Chicago
4   Edelman         Dublin, OH           Dublin
5   Test            Columbus, OH         Columbus
6   ABC             Los Angeles, CA      Los Angeles
7   DEF             Chicago, IL          Chicago
```

**Required**

```
- trim white spaces around city
- sort by desc count
- count > 1


City      Count
Chicago   3
Dublin    2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`=arrayformula( query( query( trim(D1:D), "select Col1, count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 order by count(Col1) desc", 1 ), "where Col2 > 1", 1 ) )`

The inner `query()` gets cities whose count is greater than or equal to one, and the outer `query()` filters the result so that the counts are greater than one.

Comment: also greater than 1?

Comment: I mean only include cities with more than or equal  2 (exclude 1). I tried `having count(Col1) > 1` but did not work.

Comment: This is much complex, i was expecting something like `having` clause, But it works. Happily marked as answer.